# How can I turn Structure to n-dimensional matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, structure

I have 2 matrices. 
First one is the names.
 `Names={'a','b','c'};`

Second one is Numbers.
`a=[1 3]; b=[4]; c=[2 4 5];`

Then i have the structure names which is combination of names and numbers, and they are equal some random matrices with equal rows and columns.

For this case i have 6 combination (2*1*3)  and it looks like =

```
a1.b4.c2=[7 8 9; 10 11 14];
a1.b4.c4=[2 4 5; 3 4 7];
a1.b4.c5=[3 2 11; 4 7 8];
a3.b4.c2=[1 1 1; 3 5 12];
a3.b4.c4=[2 7 9 ; 10 11 12];
a3.b4.c5=[4 2 7 ; 5 6 8];
```

I want to return this into n-dimensional matrix. In this case it is 5-dimensional which has to look like this;

```
(:,:,1,4,2)=[7 8 9; 10 11 14];     %%%% for a=1 b=4 c=2
(:,:,1,4,4)=[2 4 5; 3 4 7];        %%%% for a=1 b=4 c=4
(:,:,1,4,5)=[3 2 11; 4 7 8];       %%%% for a=1 b=4 c=5
(:,:,3,4,2)=[1 1 1; 3 5 12];       %%%% for a=3 b=4 c=2
(:,:,3,4,4)=[2 7 9 ; 10 11 12];    %%%% for a=3 b=4 c=4
(:,:,3,4,5)=[4 2 7 ; 5 6 8];       %%%% for a=3 b=4 c=5
```

I want to write a generalized code that helps me do this job for different numbers of names and numbers yet I couldnt do it. Hope you can help me! Thanks.

Comment: Is it possible, that you store all your `ax.bx.cx....` structures in one superordinated structure? In fact, from your question, I would guess, you already have such a structure named `names`!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get every combination of the possible numbers for each fields, use `ndgrid`.

```
[Numbers{1:3}] = ndgrid(a,b,c);
```

Having the numbered structures sitting in the workspace as you describe makes it messy to access them programmatically and you should avoid it if possible; however they can still be accessed using `eval`.

```
evalPattern = strjoin(strcat(Names,'%d'), '.'); % 'a%d.b%d.c%d'
firstNumbers = cellfun(@(n) n(1), Numbers); % [1 4 2]
firstElement = eval(sprintf(evalPattern,firstNumbers)); % returns the value of a1.b4.c2

result = nan([size(firstElement) size(Numbers{1}]);
for ii = 1:numel(Numbers{1})
    iiNumbers = cellfun(@(n) n(ii), Numbers);
    result(:,:,ii) = eval(sprintf(evalPattern,iiNumbers));
end
```

Comment: This works perfectly for me yet i have another question in my mind. For example, if i have more than 3 names this code will not run and i have to arrange it. Is there be a way to write this code in a generalized way that works with different number of names and numbers?

Comment: @MetehanAkıncı I've edited the answer so the application of `eval` is generalised for any number of numbers in the data structure. How you adapt the creation of the `Numbers` cell array depends how those numbers are stored in the general case, as the variable names `a`, `b` and `c` given in the question obviously don't explicitly define an arbitrary number of sets of numbers.

Comment: I just wanted to point out, that using `eval` for such tasks is considered bad practice among the MATLAB community - of course, if you care. ;-) Even MathWorks has a [special help site](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/string-evaluation.html) regarding this issue. If you still interested, I'm on a solution using only dynamic structure indexing, and could maybe provide some code tomorrow. Therefore, could you @MetehanAkıncı please reply to my comment on your original question? Thanks.

Comment: @HansHirse I did already point out in the answer that this should be avoided!

Comment: @Will Ah, I haven't understood your statements regarding this issue in that way. I'm sorry for the misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it took longer than I expected, but the following code should work for arbitrary number of names and numbers, given the following requirements:

- At the moment, names are considered to be single characters - that could be tweaked by `regexp` or something like this.
- All your `ax.bx.cx....` can be stored in some superordinated structure by your application (beforehand).
- Your struct always follows the presented order of `ax.bx.cx...`, and the matrix dimensions are equal.

So, the script is quite long and - I'm afraid - needs some explanation. Please just ask. The basic idea is to loop through the struct(s) as long as the particular "children" are still structs. That assures arbitrary "depth" of structs, i.e. number of names and numbers.

I expanded your data, so you see, that it also works for (a) additional names, (b) additional numbers, and (c) different matrix sizes. Of course, it also works on your original data.

Also, one doesn't need `Names` or `Numbers` in the beginning as these information are automatically extracted from the (has to be there superordinated) structure.

(Attention: Written in Octave. I tried to verify, that all functionality is available in Matlab, too. Please report any issues, if that's not the case. I will then refactor the code.)

```
% Structs given.
a1.b4.c2.d3 = ones(4, 4);
a1.b4.c4.d3 = ones(4, 4) * 2;
a1.b4.c5.d3 = ones(4, 4) * 3;
a1.b6.c2.d3 = ones(4, 4) * 4;
a1.b6.c4.d3 = ones(4, 4) * 5;
a1.b6.c5.d3 = ones(4, 4) * 6;
a2.b4.c2.d3 = ones(4, 4) * 7;
a2.b4.c4.d3 = ones(4, 4) * 8;
a2.b4.c5.d3 = ones(4, 4) * 9;
a2.b6.c2.d3 = ones(4, 4) * 10;
a2.b6.c4.d3 = ones(4, 4) * 11;
a2.b6.c5.d3 = ones(4, 4) * 12;

% REQUIREMENT: Store your structs in some superordinated struct.
super.a1 = a1;
super.a2 = a2;

% Initialize combined struct for names and numbers.
NamesNumbers = struct();

% Initialize Names cell array.
Names = {};

% Extract names and numbers from superordinated struct.
totalNames = 0;
totalNumbers = 1;
current = super;
while (isstruct(current))
  fields = fieldnames(current);
  totalNames = totalNames + 1;
  totalNumbers = totalNumbers * numel(fields);
  for iField = 1:numel(fields)
    field = fields{iField};
    name = field(1);
    Names{totalNames} = name;
    number = field(2:end);
    if (isfield(NamesNumbers, name) == false)
      NamesNumbers.(name) = str2num(number);
    else
      NamesNumbers.(name) = [NamesNumbers.(name) str2num(number)];
    end
  end
  current = current.(fields{1});
  if (isstruct(current) == false)
    [nRows, nCols] = size(current);
  end
end

% Extract all values from superordinated struct.
level = struct2cell(super);
while (isstruct([level{:}]))
  level = struct2cell([level{:}]);
end
values = vertcat(level{:});

% Determine indices.
maxIdx = cellfun(@(x) max(x), struct2cell(NamesNumbers));
idx = zeros([totalNumbers, totalNames]);
factorProd = 1;
for iName = 1:totalNames
  numbers = NamesNumbers.(Names{iName});
  n = numel(numbers);
  factorProd = factorProd * n;
  inner = totalNumbers / factorProd;
  resh = totalNumbers * n / factorProd;
  outer = factorProd / n;
  column = repmat(reshape(repmat(numbers, inner, 1), resh, 1), outer, 1);
  START = (iName - 1) * totalNumbers + 1;
  STOP = iName * totalNumbers;
  idx(START:STOP) = column;
end

% Initialize output.
output = zeros([nRows nCols maxIdx']);

% Fill output with values.
for iIdx = 1:size(idx, 1)
  temp = num2cell(idx(iIdx, :));
  START = (iIdx - 1) * nRows + 1;
  STOP = iIdx * nRows;
  output(:, :, temp{:}) = values(START:STOP, :);
end
```